# How can i create dim and fact table in Pentaho spoon from single sql table?

Tags: mysql, etl, pentaho, data-analysis, business-intelligence

I have one source table, which has all info. Now, i want to create a dim and fact table from this table. Lets i want to create "dim_tables, which will contain id and type. How can i create new tables from the source table?

Comment: you have to create multiple transformation, for one dimension table one transformation, for another different, like wise create and load all the dimension table, after that create new transformation for creating fact table, where you have to select your data from all the dimension table using multiple table input step.

Comment: Awesome @HelpingHand.. Thanks

I am pretty new in this field.  So lets say i have to create dim_distric table from sourse table. I will create a new transaction and then how i will create this dim_district table along with primary key.

Lets say i want to create like this::

Primarykey||Distric_name

Zone X4
Zone K3
Zone X1
Zone K1
Zone X3
Zone K2

Comment: I would recommend you to learn basics of database and pentaho, once you understand that you will get all your above answers.

Comment: you can refer this blog, http://diethardsteiner.blogspot.com/2011/11/star-schema-modeling-with-pentaho-data.html